# Как узнать свой локальный ip через Си

Tags: c, сеть, ip

Как через си можно узнать свой локальный ip

Comment: 127.0.0.1, вестимо :)

Comment: @Harry может быть ещё ::1 ;)

Comment: @Harry Хорошо xD, а если локальный ip динамический ?)

Comment: Уточнить - вы о том локальном, который типа 192.168.... - или о том, под которым вы видны в Интернете?

Comment: @Harry, скорее всего так - поднимаем сервер на 0.0.0.0 и хотим узнать все (локальные) ip, на которых он поднялся. Вроде как ip интернета тут не при чём.

Comment: @Qwertiy Т.е. то, что ipconfig вернет...

Comment: @Harry Да совершенно верно

Comment: @kombat так `system("ifconfig > file.txt")` а там уже прочитать можно)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>   //printf
#include<string.h>  //memset
#include<errno.h>   //errno
#include<sys/socket.h>  //socket
#include<netinet/in.h> //sockaddr_in
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //getsockname
#include<unistd.h>  //close


int main ( int argc , char *argv[] )
{
    const char* google_dns_server = "8.8.8.8";
    int dns_port = 53;

    struct sockaddr_in serv;

    int sock = socket ( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    //Socket could not be created
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket error");
    }

    memset( &serv, 0, sizeof(serv) );
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( google_dns_server );
    serv.sin_port = htons( dns_port );

    int err = connect( sock , (const struct sockaddr*) &serv , sizeof(serv) );

    struct sockaddr_in name;
    socklen_t namelen = sizeof(name);
    err = getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &name, &namelen);

    char buffer[100];
    const char* p = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &name.sin_addr, buffer, 100);

    if(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("Local ip is : %s \n" , buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        //Some error
        printf ("Error number : %d . Error message : %s \n" , errno , strerror(errno));
    }

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Возвращает ( Local ip is : 192.168.0.11 ) (мой локальный адрес)

Comment: А если адаптеров несколько? Плюс, похоже, при выдернутом Интернете оно работать не станет - при том, что локальная сеть все равно может вполне быть работоспособна :) И вообще, эта информация должна быть доступна даже если шнурок из компа выдернут...

Comment: Да, я тоже так подумал, если можно задать localhost по дефолту и будет всё работать

Comment: @JohnnyMc Блогадарю вас за ответ, но не могли бы вы добавить, зависимости (Библиотеки) просто в си не очень разбираюсь

Comment: @kombat Да, конечно:
include<stdio.h> //printf
include<string.h> //memset
include<errno.h> //errno
include<sys/socket.h> //socket
include<netinet/in.h> //sockaddr_in
include<arpa/inet.h> //getsockname
include<unistd.h> //close

Comment: @JohnnyMc Большое вам спасибо !!

Answer (score 4):

Под Windows - примерно так, компилил VC++.

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (!WSAStartup(WINSOCK_VERSION, &wsaData))
    {
        char chInfo[64];
        if (!gethostname(chInfo, sizeof(chInfo)))
        {
            struct hostent *sh;
            sh=gethostbyname((char*)&chInfo);
            if (sh!=NULL)
            {
                int nAdapter = 0;
                while (sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter])
                {
                    struct sockaddr_in adr;
                    memcpy(&adr.sin_addr, sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter], sh->h_length);
                    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(adr.sin_addr));
                    nAdapter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Под *nix'ы - я с ними не очень, смотрите, какие вызовы сокетов там...

Честно показало все адаптеры - и реальный, и Oracle VM, и даже тот, который через VPN подключен...  :)